# Open document in edit mode via JavaScript

Tags: 2013, javascript, edit

I run the following JavaScript to open an existing document in edit mode:

```
   url = 'https://sp.abc.com/sites/apps/Shared%20Documents/test.docx';
   baseUrl = 'https://sp.abc.com/sites/apps/';
   editDocumentWithProgID2(
         url, 
         '', 
         'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', 
         '0', 
         baseUrl, 
         '0'
   );
```

I get the following error message alert:

```
    "We're sorry, we couldn't find a program to open this document"
```

I can happily open the file in edit mode when using the context menu flyout "EDIT" link.

Any idea why I get this error message?
(BTW: running SP 2013, MDS activated).